# css property "display" not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having issues with the CSS property >display>
On my page I have hidden 4 div elements using display=none property
now using javascript I want to display each property separately 
I am able to hide the elements and am able to make them appear on click but it never displays like it should its either all inline and the formatting is wrong
I have used a lot of values for display eg: inline,block etc but i still can't get it right
if someone can help me out ill appreciate it
the code I am using is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("a").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("b").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("c").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("d").style.display="none";
function myFunctionA() {
document.getElementById("a").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("b").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("c").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("d").style.display="hidden";
}
function myFunctionB() {
document.getElementById("b").style.display="initial";
document.getElementById("a").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("c").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("d").style.display="hidden";
}
function myFunctionC() {
document.getElementById("c").style.display="initial";
document.getElementById("a").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("b").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("d").style.display="hidden";
}
function myFunctionD() {
document.getElementById("d").style.display="initial";
document.getElementById("a").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("b").style.display="hidden";
document.getElementById("c").style.display="hidden";
}
</script>
```

the page on which i see the result is :

http://theinformant.to/food-drink/

if you click on the names eg cooking, beverages you will see what am talking about

Comment: Please edit the question with more specific detail on what you want. You said that "it never displays like it should," but you never clarify how it should display. When I look at the page, it appears to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very repetitive. Try making it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). All you need is this:

```js
function myFunction(id){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
  for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.display = elements[i].id == id ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.element{display: none;} #a{display: block;}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('a')">Show A</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('b')">Show B</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('c')">Show C</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('d')">Show D</button>

<div id="a" class="element">A</div>
<div id="b" class="element">B</div>
<div id="c" class="element">C</div>
<div id="d" class="element">D</div>
```

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning DRY

Comment: thank you for the reply but you are using jquery if am not wrong. Using your example i didnt solve the problem have a look at the page now and you will see the error . thank you

Comment: is there a way i can do this using javascript

Comment: Its plain javascript. But if you think so, I see Jquery in your page view source so You can use Jquery code too.

Comment: @user2296604 As Chandana said, it is plain Javascript (no jQuery). But you need to wrap it in a `<script></script>` tag, not just paste it in your page like you did: http://i.imgur.com/NfAbj0V.png

Comment: please have a look now.
i did everything you had said but its not displaying properly. can you please help as i have been able to have it look like this but not properly

Comment: @user2296604 I'm sorry but it's 0:45am here in France, so I need to go to sleep. If no one else found the solution tomorrow, I'll have another look at it.

Comment: I appreciate if you could help me if not then its ok
thanks anyways

Comment: well i am not sure i understand what you mean but i want the div to show up once someone clicks on the entire div which has the cooking&recipes and same for the other three. It does not matter if you click the entire div or the h3 i am trying to get the functionality working . i am sorry i dont understand what do you mean when you say i need to replace the element. 
in this line :
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
we are getting the count of all the elements which have that class attached. and then you are running the entire thing through the for loop . where am i wrong?

Comment: i dont think display = block is going to help, like i said in the start display= block is displaying the entire things in a straight column where as its original shape is wide the entire div isnt showing up properly

Comment: @user2296604 If you want the entire div to react to the click, set the event on the entire div ([here is how](http://i.imgur.com/96TupUM.jpg)). From what I can see, you've solved the display problem by replacing `block` with `inline`, is that right? As for the explanation, every time this function runs, it will select all `.elements`, and for each of them, set the display property accordingly, by checking if the ID is the one you want displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `display='none'` instead of `display='hidden'`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out
i changed it but still didnt resolve the issue. The issue is that i dont know which property should i use to display it properly when clicked . Right now its all formatted wrong.

Comment: Also consider using block instead of initial.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be toggling between `display:hidden` and `display:block`, as others have said. Consider using class names instead of updating the styles directly. This will make your code more manageable going forward. Also, see @blex's answer, as he's got some good advice on making the code less repetitive.

Here's an example of using classes instead of changing styles directly:

```
/* Hide an element */
document.getElementById('a').className = 'hide';

/* Show an element */
document.getElementById('a').className = '';
```

If you need to use more than one class on the elements, try `classList.add('hide')` and `classList.remove('hide')` instead.

Then in your CSS, you could use something like this:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: i am using the code provided by @blex and i am still having the same issue. the display block works but its not displaying the outcome like it should but instead it is displaying it in one column please have a look and let me know if you have any idea. I tried replacing block with other things but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion. I see in the view source you use jQuery. Try using `$('#domelementname')` instead of `document.getElementById("a")`. There is more repetetive code.

Comment: am not using jquery i am using javascript

Comment: right click and view page scource. You should see that jquery is referred in your page. You have it.

Comment: please have a look now

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > document.write('<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>');
    window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];
    window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({
        lkid: "79197967",
        affid: "10207739",
        size: "120*600",
        type: "1",
        uid: "565258",
        language: "sp",
        web_id: "45",
        version: 110
    });
    var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),
        aff_h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    aff_s.charset = "utf-8";
    aff_s.async = !0;
    aff_s.src = "https://js.firstgrabber.com/affasi_js.min.js";
    aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild); 
</script>
```